# Why use "sealed class" and make object in Navigation? (Kotlin Jetpack Compose)

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation

I've heard the most popular way to define screen and route is to use **sealed class**
But I can't understand intuitively that way.

first is Why use **sealed class**. there are other classes including just the default class.

The second is Why use **object** in sealed class.
I think the second question is have a relation to a singleton. But why screen should be a singleton?

*this is code what I've seen*

```
sealed class Screen(val route: String) {
    object Home: Screen(route = "home_screen")
    object Detail: Screen(route = "detail_screen")
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**sealed class** is a good choice when you have routes [with arguments](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-with-args), like shown in [Jetcaster](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/2332f474336d8bbaf225dc00c845dde7c7cec300/Jetcaster/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetcaster/ui/JetcasterAppState.kt#L39) Compose sample app:

```
sealed class Screen(val route: String) {
    object Home : Screen("home")
    object Player : Screen("player/{episodeUri}") {
        fun createRoute(episodeUri: String) = "player/$episodeUri"
    }
}
```

In case when you don't have arguments in any of your routes, you can use **enum class** instead, like shown in [Owl](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/6b001f74ebe8b3cf6c18e1f55b3a495c3cc5d0fd/Owl/app/src/main/java/com/example/owl/ui/courses/Courses.kt#L104) Compose sample app:

```
enum class CourseTabs(
    @StringRes val title: Int,
    @DrawableRes val icon: Int,
    val route: String
) {
    MY_COURSES(R.string.my_courses, R.drawable.ic_grain, CoursesDestinations.MY_COURSES_ROUTE),
    FEATURED(R.string.featured, R.drawable.ic_featured, CoursesDestinations.FEATURED_ROUTE),
    SEARCH(R.string.search, R.drawable.ic_search, CoursesDestinations.SEARCH_COURSES_ROUTE)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. In sealed class, __object instanceName : className()__ statement is singleton pattern. And is that mean screen instance must defined once ?

Comment: @SeungUnOh yes, because you have only one navigation route which accepts an argument parameter, not many routes with hardcoded argument.

Comment: exactly the answer i was looking for :D