# Android Jetpack navigation - How to pass empty string in navigation arguments?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

```
AnimatedNavHost(navController, startDestination = BottomNavItem.Splash.screen_route){
composable(
            signup + "/{emailFromSignIn}" + "/{passwordFromSignIn}",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument("emailFromSignIn"){
                    type = NavType.StringType
            },navArgument("passwordFromSignIn"){
                    type = NavType.StringType
            }
}
```

```
navController.navigate(signup + "/$textEmail" + "/$textPassword")
```

How can I pass an empty string?

Error:

> Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/signup// } cannot be found in the navigation graph NavGraph(0x0) startDestination={Destination(0xb6b16c34) route=splash}

Comment: Don't forget to test your navigation argument passing for the character `$` and `/`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an [optional parameter](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#optional-args) with default empty string value:

`composable`:

```kotlin
composable(
    route = "$signup?emailFromSignIn={emailFromSignIn}&passwordFromSignIn={passwordFromSignIn}",
    arguments = listOf(
        navArgument("emailFromSignIn"){
            type = NavType.StringType
            defaultValue = ""
        },navArgument("passwordFromSignIn"){
            type = NavType.StringType
            defaultValue = ""
        }
    )
) {
```

`navigate`:

```kotlin
navController.navigate("$signup?emailFromSignIn=$textEmail&passwordFromSignIn=$textPassword")
```

Comment: How to build this route before navigate without hardcode?

Comment: @AlexS Compose Navigation operates with strings only, you have to build your own system around it to make it less hardcoded. something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69686170/3585796)

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for information on kotlin dsl navigation, the syntax is too similar.

Comment: Optional parameters only work when your url uses format "?arg1=$value1&arg2=$value2" not this format "/arg1=$value1/arg2=$value2"

Comment: @AlexS Are you looking this kind of solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77739793/3722222